# Issue Commands to QProcess once its started

Tags: c++, qt, shell, terminal, qt-creator

So in the code I have now below it loads up gphoto2 with no problem and adds the ---shell switch to it. How can I add one more line to issue a command to that shell the command i want to issue to the shell is "start-preview-stream" Thanks again!

```
    QProcess gphoto2;
    gphoto2.start("gphoto2", QStringList() << "--shell");
    if (!gphoto2.waitForStarted()){
        qDebug("gPhoto2 didn't start properly");
        return 1;
    }

    qDebug("gPhoto2 Started Successfully");
```

Debug Shows

```
gPhoto2 Started Successfully
```

I have also tried the following with no luck

```
QProcess gphoto2;
        gphoto2.start("gphoto2", QStringList() << "--shell" << "start-preview-stream");
        if (!gphoto2.waitForStarted()){
            qDebug("gPhoto2 didn't start properly");
            return 1;

        }

        qDebug("gPhoto2 Started Successfully");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to send that string to the process's standard input stream, you need to `write()` to the `QProcess`:

```
QProcess gphoto2;
gphoto2.start("gphoto2", QStringList() << "--shell");
if (!gphoto2.waitForStarted()){
    qDebug("gPhoto2 didn't start properly");
    return 1;
}

qDebug("gPhoto2 Started Successfully");

gphoto2.write("start-preview-stream\n");
```

(obviously, you'll need to add some appropriate checking of the return value etc.)

Comment: No go with your example or this one Process gphoto2;
    gphoto2.start("gphoto2", QStringList() << "--shell" << "--hook-script=qrc:/src/hook.sh");
    if (!gphoto2.waitForStarted()){
        qDebug("gPhoto2 didn't start properly");
        return 1;
    }

    qDebug("gPhoto2 Started Successfully");

     if (!gphoto2.write("start-preview-stream\n")){
        qDebug("Start preview didnt write to shell");
        return 1;
    }

        qDebug("Start Preview wrote to shell");

Comment: You might need to flush the output; I didn't have time to write and test a complete program, and the question doesn't have a [mcve] that could be easily replicated and adapted.